# parsing in array into nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, nested-object

im looking to have an end result where i passed in array values based on a key to "OR" an OR array.

```js
whereConditions = {
  "AND": [
    {
      "OR": [
        {
          "alert_type_id": {
            "equals": "9"
          }
        },
        {
          "alert_type_id": {
            "equals": "8"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "OR": [
        {
          "acknowledged_by_user_id": {
            "equals": "2"
          }
        },
        {
          "acknowledged_by_user_id": {
            "equals": "3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the data is coming from alertTypesList, acknowledgeByUserList which are arrays that store the respective data.

```js
let alertTypesList = [{id: 9, name: "foo"},{id:8, name: "bar"}]
let acknowledgeByUserList =  [{id:2, name:"foo"},{id:3, name:"bar"}]
```

currently im doing this which i dont think is very nice

```js
let whereConditions = {
    AND: []
}
let whereAlertConditions = []
let whereAckConditions = []
if(alertTypesList.length !=0){
  for (let alertType of alertTypesList){
    whereAlertConditions = [
          ...whereAlertConditions,
          {alert_type_id: {equals: alertType?.id}},
        ];
  }
}
if(acknowledgeByUserList.length !=0){
  for (let acknowledgeByUser of acknowledgeByUserList){
    whereAckConditions = [
          ...whereAckConditions,
          {acknowledged_by_user_id: {equals: acknowledgeByUser.id}},
        ];
  }
}
if(whereAlertConditions.length !=0){
  whereConditions = {
    AND: [
      ...whereConditions?.AND,
      {
        OR: whereAlertConditions,
      },
    ],
  };
}
if(whereAckConditions.length !=0){
  whereConditions = {
    AND: [
      ...whereConditions?.AND,
      {
        OR: whereAckConditions,
      },
    ],
  };
}

console.log(`whereConditions: ${JSON.stringify(whereConditions)}`)
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-playground-forked-k1fpt9?file=/src/index.js)

is there a better way to format this? i tried to parse in spread of the object in the nested whereConditions but it couldnt spread at the correct level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can simplify using js map like this:

```js
let alertTypesList = [{id: 9, name: "foo"},{id:8, name: "bar"}];
let acknowledgeByUserList =  [{id:2, name:"foo"},{id:3, name:"bar"}];

let whereConditions = {
  AND: [
    { OR: alertTypesList.map(o => ({alert_type_id: {equals: o?.id}})) },
    { OR: acknowledgeByUserList.map(o => ({acknowledged_by_user_id: {equals: o.id}})) }
  ]
};

console.log(`whereConditions: ${JSON.stringify(whereConditions)}`)
```

Base on your additional requirement in below comment here is the improvement:

```
let alertTypesList = [{ id: 9, name: "foo" }, { id: 8, name: "bar" }];
let acknowledgeByUserList = [{ id: 2, name: "foo" }, { id: 3, name: "bar" }];

function whereConditions(listAndId) {
  return {
    AND: listAndId
      .map(o => ({
        OR: o.list.map(i => ({ [o.id]: { equals: i?.id } }))
      }))
      .filter(o => (
        o.OR.length > 0
      ))
  }
}


// tests

let listAndId = [
  { list: alertTypesList, id: 'alert_type_id' },
  { list: acknowledgeByUserList, id: 'acknowledged_by_user_id' },
];
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(whereConditions(listAndId))}`);
// '{"AND":[{"OR":[{"alert_type_id":{"equals":8}},{"alert_type_id":{"equals":8}}]},{"OR":[{"acknowledged_by_user_id":{"equals":2}},{"acknowledged_by_user_id":{"equals":3}}]}]}'


listAndId = [
  { list: alertTypesList, id: 'alert_type_id' },
  { list: [], id: 'acknowledged_by_user_id' },
];
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(whereConditions(listAndId))}`);
// '{"AND":[{"OR":[{"alert_type_id":{"equals":9}},{"alert_type_id":{"equals":8}}]}]}'


listAndId = [
  { list: [], id: 'alert_type_id' },
  { list: acknowledgeByUserList, id: 'acknowledged_by_user_id' },
];
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(whereConditions(listAndId))}`);
// {"AND":[{"OR":[{"acknowledged_by_user_id":{"equals":2}},{"acknowledged_by_user_id":{"equals":3}}]}]}
```

Comment: i think i forgot to mentioned that in the event that the array is empty, it would not return an empty OR array

Comment: I've improve the code to filter empty OR